# Sensors showing bad values

Tags: linux, debian, sensors

I use Debian linux squeeze x64 now on gigabyte 970a-DS3. I installed this OS on motherboard which burned (from asus). And I've changed my motherboard to that gigabyte. 
After running back into linux, it shows I have only 13,9 °C temperatures and is it only 1 sensor (instead of about 3 or 4 sensors), which it has detected.

it shows just:

```
Debx64>sensors
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +13.9°C  (high = +70.0°C, crit = +86.0°C)
```

I searched on google, but nothing there helping me.

I was trying to reinstall lm_sensors, trying again sensors-detect |y and nothing was working.

Why it doesn't show all of my sensors and why it shows only 1 sensors with totaly low temperature (13.9°C is epic fail...)

What to do, to fix this problem? Is there anything how to tell linux "I want to search  again all devices, which has any sensors"?

I know this is unique problem, but I would like to know, how to solve this problem.

Thank you, all for helping me

Comment: Each motherboard has its own calibration parameters. It looks like yours aren't supported, you'll need to find the values somewhere (hopefully someone has found them and put them up on the web somewhere) and add them to `/etc/sensors.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [specification](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4122#sp) your MB is based on the iTE IT8728 chip which [is not supported](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Devices) by lm-sensors. Sorry.

Comment: ...is there any possibility, how to add older driver for almost same mobos? For example - when there was K10 CPUs, and there wasn't K10 driver for CPU, K10 was compatible with K8, so it worked. Is it possible here?

Comment: May be [it helps](http://www.lm-sensors.org/wiki/Configurations/Gigabyte/H67MA-UD2H)

Comment: where to put it in?

Answer (score 0):

This is really old, but there is a solution if still somebody needs it.

There are two forks of kernel modules supporting the iTE IT8728 chip and a dozen others:

- [Fork 1 by a1wong](https://github.com/a1wong/it87)
- [Fork 2 by rpavlik](https://github.com/rpavlik/it87)

I don't know what's the difference, but I used the first one with my Asus PRIME x370 Pro motherboard. This had been the solution for my Proxmox installation (debian based). Adopt for your distibution:

```
# install the kernel headers. might differ for other distributions.
apt install pve-headers gcc

# get the sources, build and install the kernel module.
git clone https://github.com/a1wong/it87.git
make
make install
modprobe it87

# test it. 
sensors-detect       # just press enter for all questions.
sensors              # now there should be more sensor info.

# todo add kernel module into startup scripts.
cd /etc/modules-load.d/
echo it87.conf > it87.conf

# ensure the module is built and installed every time a new kernel ist installed.
# we just install it every time an apt action is performed. it's fast and better do it once too often.
echo 'DPkg::Post-Invoke {"cd /root/lm-sensors-kernel-modules/it87 && make && make install";};' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/82AsusLmSensorsIt87KernModule
```